# How does SSAS Multidimensional engine works?

Tags: ssas, cube, msbi, multidimensional-cube

I was googling about "How does SSAS Multidimensional works?" but unfortunately couldn't get any related post.

Basically my question is how does it's engine works and why it works faster than the SQL server database. I actually want to know the backend of it's engine.

Please help me with the links or post to get the brief knowledge about it's evaluation context.

I've been working on SSAS tabular model since last around one year now I've got a projects where in I've to develop a Multidimensional Model.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: *I actually want to know the backend of it's engine* - This is far too broad a question for SO.  If you don't have a specific problem, then you will need to buy and read a textbook.

Comment: could you suggest me any books @iamdave